# Random Word Generator that stores all previously generated words into a separate file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, csv, random

***My Python Level: Beginner***

**MY QUESTION:** If I wanted to make a random word generator that could show me all of the generated words previously produced (in a separate CSV file, for example), how would I do that?

This seems like it should be fairly simple, but I don't know what to look up to solve this problem. My thoughts were to use a loop somehow, keep reassigning values, or just copy/paste the newly generated words into another document every time I click Run.

---

**An example:**

Randomly Generated Words

Run #1 Output: `['dog', 'cat', 'bag']`

Run #2 Output:  `['tree', 'hug', 'food']`

.
.
.

Run #10 Output: `['hamburger', 'tree', 'desk']`

This updated CSV file would include ALL words that were randomly generated from the previous times the program was run and look something like this:

```
['dog', 'cat', 'bag', 'tree', 'hug', 'food', ..., 'word_x', 'word_x', 'word_x', ..., 'hamburger', 'tree', 'desk']
```

*(I added 'tree' again to show that repetition is okay for this project)*

---

This is what I have so far:

***Note: This is a reduced version of the data I'm actually using***

```
word_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'hungry', 'food', 'hamburger', 'desk', 'bag', 'rain', 'car']
    
rand_word_rep = random.choices(word_list, k=3)
print(rand_word_rep)
```

Output

```
['dog', 'desk', 'car']
```

---

**MY QUESTION (Again):** If I wanted to make a random word generator that could show me all of the generated words previously produced (in a separate CSV file, for example), how would I do that?

---

Hopefully, I was clear in this post. If not, please let me know of your confusion and I'll clarify. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write to the file normally.

```py
def write(data, filename):
    with open(filename, 'a') as f:
        f.write('\n'.join(data) + '\n')

def read(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

def clear(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w'):
        pass

word_list = ['dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'hungry', 'food', 'hamburger', 'desk', 'bag', 'rain', 'car']
    
rand_word_rep = random.choices(word_list, k=3)

write(rand_word_rep, 'chosen_words.txt')
```

After `['dog', 'cat', 'bag']`, the file would look like:

```
dog
cat
bag
```

After `['tree', 'hug', 'food']`, the file would look like:

```
dog
cat
bag
tree
hug
food
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can write lines into a file like this:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'at') as f:
    f.write('this\n')
```

The `'a'` means 'append' and the `'t'` means 'text'. Note that you are responsible for writing the lines to the file with the newline character.

Now you can read this file into a list:

```py
with open('data.txt', 'rt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
```

Note that the file mode changed to `'rt'` for 'read text'.

The newlines are in there too; you can strip them off with `str.strip()`, for example.